# How to set maxLines and ellipsize of a TextView at the same time

Tags: android

I want to limit my text view to have maximum of 5 lines, so I did:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:maxLines="5" />
```

But when I try to configure it to add '...' when the text is truncated, I add android:ellipsize="end".  I do see the ... but then my TextView only has a max line of 2, instead of 5.

Can you please suggest how can I make the text view of maximum line of 5 and add '...' when it get truncated?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Maybe you could post your answer below for the reference of other users

Comment: Try remove this line: android:ellipsize="..."

Comment: For me, it does really work when `ellipsize` is removed. Instead of '...' I use `setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled` and `setFadingEdgeLength`.

Comment: How did you fix that? @michael

Answer (score 63):

Progrmatically, you can use:

```
your_text_view.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
your_text_view.setMaxLines(4);
your_text_view.setText("text");
```

Comment: This does not work for me it always sets it for 1 line

Comment: Check your xml file. Might be your TextView can have android:maxLines = "1". If it is remove it.

Comment: For me its not there working is a definite bug in Android.  If I use the treeObserver method.

Answer (score 27):

try this code...

```
    final TextView tv_yourtext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    tv_yourtext.setText("A really long text");
    ViewTreeObserver vto = tv_yourtext.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ViewTreeObserver obs = tv_yourtext.getViewTreeObserver();
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            if(tv_yourtext.getLineCount() > 6){
                Log.d("","Line["+tv_yourtext.getLineCount()+"]"+tv_yourtext.getText());
                int lineEndIndex = tv_yourtext.getLayout().getLineEnd(5);
                String text = tv_yourtext.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex-3)+"...";
                tv_yourtext.setText(text);
                Log.d("","NewText:"+text);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: This code works perfectly for me! @michael, if it works for you, you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: I get a question. what is the function of the following  code.   ViewTreeObserver obs = tv_yourtext.getViewTreeObserver();
  obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);   C an I use vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this) instead? Thanks.

Comment: using `RecyclerView.Adapter TextView` not set text check this my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790803/using-viewtreeobserver-i-am-adding-setmaxlines-and-setellipsize-in-materialtextv

Answer (score 22):

Apparently you have to specify the `inputType` and set it to `none` in this case. 
It should look something like this:

```
<TextView
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:inputType="none"
  android:maxLines="2"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, although that doesindeed truncate, there are no ellipses at the end.

Answer (score 13):

You only need to add this line to your TextView:

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

Comment: It does not work for me when I need 2 lines at most and "..." at the end

Answer (score 6):

There is same question [android ellipsize multiline textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview) This is known bug, quite old and not fixed yet :(

someone posted workaround http://code.google.com/p/android-textview-multiline-ellipse/ maybe it will help you (or someone else)

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:maxLines="5"
android:ellipsize="end" />
```

Works for me, make sure TextView top container should have height like

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

When I set the TextView height to a constant value (like 50dp), it works fine for me.