# Android TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have an Android TextView where the view itself is limited to four lines. If the text exceeds this limit I want the end of the view to end with something like .. <-- to notify that there is more text here so you can click and open in fullscreen for example. Not just suddenly stop in the middle of a sentence. Is there a quick fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`android:ellipsize="end"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize) attribute in your layout XML file. It may still stop in the middle of a sentence, but it will have an ellipsis (...) at the end.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Only problem now is that the text ends after two lines no matter what. Have set android:maxLines="4". Any idea? Goes up to four lines without the code you gave.

Comment: Hmmmm...based on the documentation, it looks like `android:ellipsize` may be designed for a single line, not multiple lines. I do not know why you are getting two lines of output instead of 1 or 4, though. Do you have `android:minLines` or `android:minHeight` defined?

Comment: No, only maxLines is set. Tried both commands you gave, but still only two lines. Tricky this one..

Comment: This is because of a bug in Android.  This solution will not work for your case.  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2254

Comment: Okay, I've created a workaround that should be helpful under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview/6763689#6763689

Answer (score 1):

Go to the layout file which contains this textview and place following attribute

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

There are 4 options. start, end, middle or marquee. Since you want dots at the end use "end" value

Answer (score 0):

```
android:maxLines="4"
android:ellipsize="end"
```