# Is the xml attribute singleLine deprecated or not in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, attributes, textview, android-singleline

`singleLine` is/was used in xml layout files for `TextView` and `EditText` something like the following:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

[Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16381219/3681880) on SO say `singleLine` is deprecated, while [other people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24970871/3681880) still suggest using it. Sometimes it even seems necessary to use when `maxLines="1"` doesn't work. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30029722/3681880), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17125324/3681880), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351698/textviews-ellipsize-not-working-on-maxlines-1))

The docs should be the place to go to answer this question, right? [Here, they say:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine)

> **This constant was deprecated in API level 3.**
>
> This attribute is
>   deprecated. Use `maxLines` instead to change the layout of a static
>   text, and use the `textMultiLine` flag in the inputType attribute
>   instead for editable text views (if both singleLine and inputType are
>   supplied, the inputType flags will override the value of singleLine).

However, [in the TextView docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), there is no indication that it is deprecated, either for [`android:singleLine`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine) or for [`setSingleLine`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSingleLine%28%29) or for [`setTransformationMethod`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTransformationMethod%28android.text.method.TransformationMethod%29). The same TextView docs, by comparison, do state that other things like `STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN` and `fitSystemWindows` are deprecated. So is the `singleLine` deprecation an omission, was it "undeprecated", or what?

This question has been [previously asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026121/androidsingleline-of-textview-is-nolonger-in-the-deprecated) but was not the main focus of the question (and was not answered).

Comment: In which cases _maxLines="1"_ doesn't work ?

Comment: can you post the `code` block for both the cases?

Comment: I'm not really asking here why a particular instance of `maxLines="1"` supposedly doesn't work. (It could be that it really does work in every instance.) I just want to know if `singleLine` is really deprecated or not. That being said, I don't have any authoritative examples but see the `ellipsize="marquee"` part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30029722/3681880) and [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351698/textviews-ellipsize-not-working-on-maxlines-1) and also [this answer with comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10748836/3681880).

Comment: I faced a strange side effect of singleLine attribute - I used `TextView`s with it in `ViewPager` and the pager did not respond to touch slide events, if I slided with finger over that `TextView`s. But when I changed that attribute to maxLines=1, everything went ok!

Comment: @JafarKhQ There are some cases where it behaves inferiorly, particularly with ellipsizing.

Answer (score 49):

I think the answer to your question is already in one of the SO [posts you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17125324/779983). Unfortunately, the deprecation of `singleLines` is not a black-or-white matter.

It *is* deprecated, but it is *not* going anywhere anytime soon.

**It was deprecated because** its performance is poor, relative to its successor, `maxLines`. It uses [`SingleLineTransformationMethod`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/method/SingleLineTransformationMethod.java) to replace newlines and carriage returns in the String you place in the `TextView`, unlike `maxLines`, which "just" adjusts the height of the `TextView` based on the number of lines and does no String replacing.

This method of replacing characters also meant that `singleLine` could [break in unexpected ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6492074/779983) (e.g. if you use custom fonts). It was these performance and reliability issues that led to its deprecation.

However, **it is not going anywhere because**, as the SO post you linked to states, it is still in use by many old Android applications, *and* it is still useful sometimes (e.g. when you want to show the *entire* text on one line and ignore carriage-returns and newlines).

Do note that deprecation does not necessarily mean that an API is going away. It just means that its use is discouraged, but may be permitted.

Comment: If it is actually deprecated, then isn't it the official practice to mark it as so throughout the documentation? Yet the TextView docs don't do that. That's what makes me wonder whether this is an oversight or if it is being purposefully vague or something else.

Comment: @Suragch yes, it is likely an oversight (it wouldn't be the first oversight in Android docs). Keep in mind that it was deprecated very early on in Android's development. In fact, the [git commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d24b8183b93e781080b2c16c487e60d51c12da31/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml#L1701) that deprecated it is one of the first ones in Github's import of Android source and is dated April 2009. It was deprecated very early on in development, but not all docs were updated.

Comment: I'm not sure why the documentation would recommend using `maxLines`. It does not supply the same behavior as `singleLine`.

Answer (score 21):

The deprecated attribute was added in change [d24b8183b9](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/d24b8183b93e781080b2c16c487e60d51c12da31) which is nothing but a dump from Google's internal SCM:

> auto import from //branches/cupcake/...@130745

As can be seen from the change `core/res/res/values/attrs.xml` [diff](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/d24b8183b93e781080b2c16c487e60d51c12da31%5E!/#F366) adds the @deprecated doc comment, but `core/java/android/widget/TextView.java` [diff](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/d24b8183b93e781080b2c16c487e60d51c12da31%5E%21/#F198) does not alter anything from `setSingleLine()`'s doc comment.

Now without access to Google's internal SCM history, it is not possible to know what exactly caused above change in `attrs.xml` doc comment, but for your question

> So is the `singleLine` deprecation an omission, was it "undeprecated", or what?

one possible answer is:`TextView`'s single-line was neither deprecated, nor "undeprecated", but it was enhanced to take into account whether the view is editable, a password field or uses any other input type flag that affects single/multi-lineness.

Comment: Several of the answers here provide some useful discussion and insight into this problem, but since the bounty time is almost up, I am awarding it to this answer because it goes into the most depth and draws the most from credible and official sources. I'm not quite ready to choose an accepted answer, yet, though.

Answer (score 11):

Just for adding some more information to the discussion, Lint now has the following error:

"Combining `ellipsize` and `maxLines=1` can lead to crashes on some devices. Earlier versions of lint recommended replacing `singleLine=true` with `maxLines=1` but that should not be done when using `ellipsize`.

More info: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36950033"

So, I guess that `singleLine` is now, and I think we should come up with a new term... "deprecatedish"?

Comment: This comment is 4 years old. FOUR years ago this was "deprecatedish" and unclear, and now it still ist. This is insanity.

Answer (score 9):

In the official grepcode of [`TextView`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView) (v5.1.0 r1) :

`android:singleLine` is not annotated with `@Deprecated`.

I also see this in [`setInputType`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setInputType%28int%29) method:

```
boolean singleLine = !isMultilineInputType(type);

// We need to update the single line mode if it has changed or we
// were previously in password mode.
if (mSingleLine != singleLine || forceUpdate) {
    // Change single line mode, but only change the transformation if
    // we are not in password mode.
    applySingleLine(singleLine, !isPassword, true);
}
```

`setInputType` overrides the `mSingleLine` value so.

EDIT : 
This xml attribute is now officially deprecated. ([since API 3?](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine)). It is now visible in AndroidStudio xml editor.

Answer (score 5):

Just thought I'll add that Android Studio 2.2.1 flags singleLine as deprecated.
However, what I found is that in my instance:

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

works well, whereas

```
android:maxLines="2"
```

does not.

Answer (score 5):

While Android Studio claims that it is deprecated, in reality we had an edit text which should allow itself to be only single-line.

Adding `maxLines="1"` made it allow newline characters, which is not suitable for our needs.

So we went back to using `singleLine="true"`.

Answer (score 5):

`singleLine` IS deprecated. No discussion needed.
 
The only problem is the wrong documentation.
 "use the `textMultiLine` flag in the `inputType` attribute instead for editable text views" is the direct opposite of what you want to achieve by using `singleLine`.
 
Instead of that you can use **`android:inputType="text"`**. 
For me it did exactly what I wanted - an edit with a single line without line breaks.

Comment: The OP described why discussion is needed. Declaring "no discussion needed" without citing a credible source as to why the issue is closed doesn't help.

Answer (score 5):

I have just added `android:inputType="text"`and removed `android:maxLines="1"`, it worked fine for me.

Comment: I removed singleLine attribute and i did your answer, it works for me congratulations !

Answer (score 1):

Only providing `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:minLines="1"` wont solve the issue of keyboard `actionNext` related issue. Use `android:inputType="text"` for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Simple alternate way, use: `android:maxLines="1"`