# TextView singleLine

Tags: android, textview, textinput

I want to create a textview with a single line which is inside a swipelayout. Every textview represents an action on which the user can touch. All textviews have a width of 100dp. Now i have the problem that the text of a textview is too long and it wraps to the next line. I don't want to use `android:singleLine="true"`. Now i added `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:inputType="text"` and **it works fine**. But now i get the warning:

> Attribute android:inputtype should not be used with <`TextView`>: Change
>   element type to <`EditText`>

I don't want to enter text so i don't need an `EditText`.

Is there another way or should i just ignore this warning?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_list_bottom_rename"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_visibility_white_36dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/rename"
    android:textColor="@color/item_title_listname"/>
```

**Solution:**

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_list_bottom_rename"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_visibility_white_36dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/rename"
        android:textColor="@color/item_title_listname"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read what it says ?

> Using a `<TextView>` to input text is generally an error, you should be
>   using `<EditText>` instead. EditText is a subclass of TextView, and some
>   of the editing support is provided by TextView, so it's possible to
>   set some input-related properties on a TextView. However, using a
>   TextView along with input attributes is usually a cut & paste error.
>   To input text you should be using `<EditText>`.

**InputType** -*Bit definitions for an integer defining the basic content type of text held in an **Editable** object. Supported classes may be combined with variations and flags to indicate desired behaviors.*

Attribute `android:editable` should not be used with `<TextView>` and thats the reason!

you can remove that `inputType` in your `textView`

---

without `android:singleLine="true"` but with `android:maxLines="1"`

**Alternatives**

1.use what compiler asks :P  `EditText` and make it act as textView

```
<EditText
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Helloo"
    android:id="@+id/Id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
</EditText>
```

2.you can also use

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_list_bottom_rename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Heloo" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I didn't use `android:editable` and **i don't want to edit** my `TextView`. As far as i know since `android:singleLine="true"` is deprecated, `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:inputType="text"` should be used instead. My code works fine i just wanted to know if i should ignore the warning or if there is another way.

Comment: neither i said that you used  `android:editable` look at it again what i said was about **InputType** and its definition

Comment: Yes i read it but how should i provide a single line without using `android:singleLine="true"` or `android:inputType="text"`?

Comment: why you want to use `android:inputType="text"` you can remove that line

Comment: Because as i said, as far as i know the combination of `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:inputType="text"` should be use instead of `android:singleLine="true"`. If i just use `android:maxLines="1"` **without** `android:inputType="text"`, then the text of the `TextView` is just cutted.

Comment: @beeb The inputType="text" does nothing for non-editabe TextViews.  Its only sent as a parameter to the keyboard.  So you can safely remove it, it will not change the display.  I also don't know why you think singleLine=true is deprecated, it isn't.  Check the docs.

Comment: The thing is **it does change the display**! If not i would delete `android:inputType="text"`. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/30315287/6632568 
for a discussion on SO why it's deprecated. And Android Studio tells mee too that it's deprecated.

Comment: says hi to @Gabe Sechan and beeb you can use HorizontalScrollView with maxLines=1

Comment: @beeb how was that?

Comment: Nice that works too. I'm still wondering why `android:inputType="text"` has the same effect... I think it's much overhead to wrap the textfield like this instead of a single code line. Do you recommend this solution instead of ignoring the warning?

Comment: @beeb Not deprecated in AS for me, not deprecated in the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine.  The page you reference says deprecated since version 3, I can assure you it hasn't been-  I've been using it for the last 6 years without seeing any deprecation warnings.

Comment: @beeb i recommend  you to use `singleLine=true` as my knowledge .. even there is an argument about API 3 will not be removed because it's still the only way to make some effects that `android:maxLines` can't make

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers and time. @Charuka i accepted your answer. I tested very much and i will use your second solution with `HorizontalScrollView`. That's exactly what i need. I set the `minWidth="100"` and if there is a text which is longer, the textview will increase it's width.