# Android: TextView ellipsize multiline

Tags: android, textview, truncate, multiline

How can I make a multiline TextView that truncates the text properly? My TextView is part of a TableRow, so its width is a weight. The following does not work. The result is simply truncated text without the ellipses. I'm using API 10 (Android 2.3.3).

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_recipe"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:text="Fried pork with mushrooms and potatoes and cilantro"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
```

Reducing the two lines to a single line with the following does work, but it's not ideal:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

I don't like this for two reasons:

1. *android:singleLine* is deprecated

   I'd much prefer to have the text be on two lines than one.

I've seen discussion about this like from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview) but I'm hoping a new solution has been found by now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it's from my project and works on phone but unfortunately not on tablet emulator:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/myItem"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="2" />
```

Comment: Hi ania, this does not seem to work. The text is still cut off without any ellipses. What version of Android are you developing on?

Comment: Sorry, holidays :) android version is 2.1+. It is not working for tablets.

Answer (score 0):

Use lines="1" as all the other methods are deprecated. As well as set scrollHorizontally.

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/myid" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:lines="1"       
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

Comment: Hi Pete, unfortunately this does not work either. The ellipses simply don't show up. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Pete, shouldn't `scrollHorizontally` be `false` if you want to do `android:ellipsize="end"`. (It should be `true` if you want to do `android:ellipsize="marquee"`.)