# Meaning of the ellipsise options

Tags: android, ellipsis

I see that there are 4 different values to `android:ellipsize`:

*none,start,mid,end* and *marquee*

What is the meaning and effect of setting each of these?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview

Answer (score 35, accepted):

See the below image to know how `android:ellipsize` works
[image]

I have used following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:maxLines="4" 
        android:ellipsize="none" 
        android:singleLine="false" 
        android:text="Hi make this a very long string that wraps at least 4 lines, seriously make it really really long so it gets cut off at the fourth line not joke.  Just do it!" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip" />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:maxLines="4" 
        android:ellipsize="start" 
        android:singleLine="false" 
        android:text="Hi make this a very long string that wraps at least 4 lines, seriously make it really really long so it gets cut off at the fourth line not joke.  Just do it!" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip" />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:maxLines="4" 
        android:ellipsize="middle" 
        android:singleLine="false" 
        android:text="Hi make this a very long string that wraps at least 4 lines, seriously make it really really long so it gets cut off at the fourth line not joke.  Just do it!" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip" />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:maxLines="4" 
        android:ellipsize="end" 
        android:singleLine="false" 
        android:text="Hi make this a very long string that wraps at least 4 lines, seriously make it really really long so it gets cut off at the fourth line not joke.  Just do it!" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip" />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:maxLines="4" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee" 
        android:text="Hi make this a very long string that wraps at least 4 lines, seriously make it really really long so it gets cut off at the fourth line not joke.  Just do it!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: cant be explained better .. so marquee and end has same effect .I was using in my textview marquee and it was not coming on device and just tried testing with end and its coming . Any comment on this behavior.Thank you very much

Comment: You set `android:maxLines="4"`, and TextViews have 2 lines. Why?

Comment: Middle and start ellipsize don't work for Honeycomb and later version of Android.

Comment: @Mike that is not necessarily true (at least on Nexus 5 running Android L in Jan 2016)

Comment: for the case by @png, you need to set `singleLine=true`. interestingly, when you combo `ellipsize=marquee` & `singleLine=true`, you don't get the deprecation warning.