# Android, How to limit width of TextView (and add three dots at the end of text)?

Tags: android, textview, ellipsis

I have a `TextView` that I want to limit characters of it. Actually, I can do this but the thing that I'm looking for is how to add three dots (...) at the end of string. This one shows the text has continue. This is my XML but there is no dots although it limit my text.

```
<TextView 
        android:id                      = "@+id/tvFixture"
        android:layout_width            = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height           = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf         = "@id/ivFixture_Guest"
        android:text                    = "@string/test_06"
        android:lines                   = "1"
        android:ems                     = "3"
        android:gravity                 = "right"
        style                           = "@style/simpletopic.black" 
        android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

Answer (score 860, accepted):

**Deprecated:**

Add one more property `android:singleLine="true"` in your Textview

**Updated:**

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: Definitely need singleLine when I just attempted this. Even though it says deprecated.

Comment: android:singleLine="true" is deprecated and has bad side effects.
use android:ellipsize="end" and maxLine="1" instead

Comment: What are the "bad side effects" of using `singleLine`? See also: [Is the xml attribute singleLine deprecated or not in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028697/is-the-xml-attribute-singleline-deprecated-or-not-in-android)

Comment: btw, android:maxLines can be greater than 1 if you want :)

Comment: Has anyone got this msg " W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1" >?

Comment: @COLDICE I just started seeing this pop up, I wonder if it came in with the new update. Seems like a bug.

Comment: when you use deprecated 'singleLine' the hint says you should use 'maxLines' instead, but there is not a single word about 'ellipsize'. Ahhrr! Was it so hard to add a couple of words of how to make a simple TextView single lined? Why should we check Stackoverflow for such a trivial thing?

Comment: you can use android:lines="1" too

Comment: Sometimes you might need app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" also

Comment: If i use maxLines=1, the text sometimes truncates after 10 characters, sometimes 15, sometimes more or less. So, I used singleLine=true and that solved this issue.

Comment: If singleLine is deprecated, then why is it still in the android documentation? Without any mention of deprecation?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:singleLine

Comment: For me it only works with `singleLine` although it's deprecated. Weird

Answer (score 187):

The following is what I learned by playing around with various options for forcing a `TextView` to a single line (with and without the three dots).

[image]

## android:maxLines="1"

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="one two three four five six seven eight nine ten" />
```

This just forces the text to one line. Any extra text is hidden.

Related:

- [android:maxLines](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines)
- [android:singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine) (Note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028697/is-singleline-depricated-or-not-in-android) and [this](http://radleymarx.com/blog/15-quirky-android-xml-layout-parameters-to-know/))
- [android:lines](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lines)

## ellipsize="end"

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="one two three four five six seven eight nine ten" />
```

This cuts off the text that doesn't fit but lets users know that the text has been truncated by adding an ellipsis (the three dots).

Related:

- ellipsize="start"  (...aaabbbccc)
- ellipsize="middle" (aaa...ccc)
- [android: Ellipsise , meaning of the options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739721/android-ellipsise-meaning-of-the-options)

## ellipsize="marquee"

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/MarqueeText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:text="one two three four five six seven eight nine ten" />
```

This makes the text scroll automatically across the TextView. Note that [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3333855/3681880) it needs to be set in code:

```
textView.setSelected(true);
```

Supposedly `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:singleLine="true"` should do basically the same thing and since singleLine is [apparently deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028697/is-singleline-depricated-or-not-in-android) I would prefer not to use it, but when I take it out, the marquee doesn't scroll anymore. Taking `maxLines` out doesn't affect it, though.

Related:

- [Marquee text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android)

## HorizontalScrollView with scrollHorizontally

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="one two three four five six seven eight nine ten" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This allows the user to manually scroll to see the whole line of text.

Comment: But this is just ellipsizing at the end of every word. Is there any way to add ... in the middle of a very_long_word_without_whitespace... ?

Comment: @TobiasReich, I'm not aware of a built in way to accomplish that. You could make your own using [Paint.measureText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Sometimes you might need app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" also

Answer (score 90):

Try this property of TextView in your layout file..

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 32):

I take it you want to limit width to one line and not limit it by character? Since `singleLine` is deprecated, you could try using the following together:

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 17):

eg. you can use

```
android:maxLength="13"
```

this will restrict texview length to 13  but problem is if you try to add 3 dots(...), it wont display it, as it will be part of textview length.

```
     String userName;
     if (data.length() >= 13) {
            userName = data.substring(0, 13)+ "...";

     } else {

            userName = data;

    }
        textView.setText(userName);
```

apart from this you have to use

```
 android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: You should better use "\u2026" instead of "..."

Comment: this was just as an example. if I'm putting strings in Strings.xml then definitely I go for unicodes. Any specific reason you want to put here ?

Comment: Nope. I personally have recently learned of the existence of this character in the Unicode and decided to share this knowledge ;)

Answer (score 12):

Use

- `android:singleLine="true"`
- `android:maxLines="1"`
- `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`

It's how my full `TextView` looks:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="NAME PLACEHOLDER MORE Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"

    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/message_check_sign"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img_chat_contact"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/img_chat_contact" />
```

[image: Picture of <code>TextView</code>]

Answer (score 8):

Steps to add '...' at end of the text if it is too long:

1. check that the text width is constant
2. add these two lines
   `android:ellipsize="end" android:maxLines="1"`

Complete code of textview in constraint layout:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Multiple other answer such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48319801/10952503) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30029722/10952503) already explain everything that you say, so when you will have enough reputation, you will be able to upvote them instead of making duplicate

Comment: android:ellipsize="end" and specially android:maxLines="2" it turned out nice. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I am using Horizonal Recyclerview. 
1) Here in CardView, TextView gets distorted vertically when using

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Check the bold TextViews Wyman Group, Jaskolski...
[image]

2) But when I used singleLine along with ellipsize -

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Check the bold TextViews Wyman Group, Jaskolski...
[image]

2nd solution worked for me properly (using singleLine). Also I have tested in OS version: 4.1 and above (till 8.0), it's working fine without any crashes.

Answer (score 5):

code:

```
TextView your_text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_id_textview);
your_text_view.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```

xml:

```
android:maxLines = "5"
```

e.g.

In Matthew 13, the disciples asked Jesus why He spoke to the crowds in parables. He answered, "It has been given to you to know the mysteries of the kingdom of heaven, but to them it has not been given.

Output:
In Matthew 13, the disciples asked Jesus why He spoke to the crowds in parables. He answered, "It has been given to you to know...

Answer (score 4):

You can limit your textview's number of characters and add (...) after the text. 
Suppose You need to show 5 letters only and thereafter you need to show (...), Just do the following :

```
String YourString = "abcdefghijk";

if(YourString.length()>5){

YourString  =  YourString.substring(0,4)+"...";

your_text_view.setText(YourString);
}else{

 your_text_view.setText(YourString); //Dont do any change

}
```

a little hack ^_^. Though its not a good solution. But a work around which worked for me :D

**EDIT:**
I have added check for less character as per your limited no. of characters.

Comment: [It's already explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748796/android-how-to-limit-width-of-textview-and-putting-three-dots-at-the-end-of-te/16580374#16580374)

Answer (score 4):

I got the desired result by using

```
android:maxLines="2"
android:minLines="2"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

The trick is set maxLines and minLines to the same value... and Not just android:lines = "2", dosen't do the trick. 
Also you are avoiding any deprecated attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add following lines into your layout for the textview

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 4):

In order to work with the **android:ellipsize** attribute, you have to limit the **layout width** of the *TextView*, such that the *text* is out of bounds from view of TextView.

So, **android:layout_width** attribute plays a key role here, set it accordingly.

One *example* can be:

```
<TextView        
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="This is a very long text to be displayed"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:maxLines="1"            
     />
```

Now, here if the *text* in **android:text="This is a very long text to be displayed"** goes out of view from TextView with a **android:layout_width="120dp"**, **android:ellipsize="end"** will truncate the *text* and place **...(3 dots)** after it. i.e. ***This is very long...*** will be displayed in the TextView.

Answer (score 4):

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_description"
            android:layout_width="165dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:text="Pack of 4 summer printed pajama"
            android:textColor="#d2131c"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you give fix height and width of text view. Then your solution will work.

Answer (score 3):

you can write this line in xml where you take the `textview` :

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach of @AzharShaikh works fine.

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

But I realize a trouble that TextView will be truncated by word (in default). Show if we have a text like:

***test long_line_without_any_space_abcdefgh***

the TextView will display:

***test...***

And I found solution to handle this trouble, replace spaces with the unicode no-break space character, it makes TextView wrap on characters instead of words:

```
yourString.replace(" ", "\u00A0");
```

The result:

***test long_line_without_any_space_abc...***

Answer (score 2):

Apart from

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxLines="1"
```

you should set

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

also know as "match constraint", because the `wrap_content` value just expands the box to fit the whole text, and the `ellipsize` property can't make its effect.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple for three dots**

```
android:layout_width="100dp" <!--your dp or match_parent or 0dp>
android:maxLines="2" <!--count your line>
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add These two lines in your text

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

In this way you can set the maximum length of the view and, at the same time, you will have dots at the end ("num" is your number of dp):

```
android:maxWidth="{num}dp"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by `xml`:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:maxLines="1" // or any number of lines you want
    android:ellipsize="end"
    />
```

Comment: How can I put 3 `Dots` @ end  with `maxLength="35"` property any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

set `android:maxLength="8"` in `Textview`

if you want to set yourString >5. then set textview length 5+3  (for three-dot)

```
if (yourString.length()>5) // 
    {
        textview.setText(yourString.substring(0,5)+"...");
    }
    else {
        textview.setText(title);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.set static `width like 7odp`

2.use  `android:ellipsize="end"`

3.use  `android:maxLines="1"`

4.use  `android:singleLine="true"`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_status"
        **android:layout_width="70dp"**
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_8"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black_2a"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_1"
        **android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"**
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:borrowStatusText="@{item.lenders[0].status}"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_vector"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You just change ...

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Use this below line

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

.......

```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/visitBox"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

             <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/txvrequestTitle"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:text="Abcdefghighiklmnon"
                  android:textAppearance="? 
                  android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                  android:textColor="@color/orange_color" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: singleLine is deprecated