# Set value for textview when it too long

Tags: android

At the moment,I have textView and I want to check if in one device,
if textview display more one lines.I will get the first lines.Then remove last three character and replace by "..."
if textview display not full width of device,i will display full text.
This is xml file of textview

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewListSuggest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

How must I do?

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

[android:singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine)

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748796/android-how-to-limit-width-of-textview-and-putting-three-dots-at-the-end-of-te)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your text view:

android:singleLine="true"

android:ellipsize="end"