# I am building an application using Android Studio

Tags: android

I  am using Android Studio.I want to use "View More" after some letters in a textview. I have searched for it and it shows how to add "View More" after a specific number of lines but I want to add it after a specific number of letters. Can anybody suggest what should I do?

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is the purpose of doing that? Is it some kind of game where the person tries to guess what the word is?

Comment: Try this it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748796/android-how-to-limit-width-of-textview-and-add-three-dots-at-the-end-of-text

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem

Suppose you have a String

```
String name="Rajdev Stack overflow"
```

name has 21 characters/letters(including spaces).

If you want to show only upto 10 charchters and then view more, you can trim this String upto first 10 characters.

```
String trimmedName = name.substring(0, Math.min(name.length(), 10));
```

Now trimmedName contains only upto 10 characters. Now you can do:

```
trimmedName+"... view more";
```

so the user will see 10 characters and then view more

```
Rajdev Sta... view more
```