# Show three dots when TextView is too long

Tags: android, textview

One would think that showing three dots in 2019 at the end of string will be easy, but the opposite seems to be true. I have tried:

```
maxLines="1"
drawablePadding="10dp"
ellipsize="end"
ellipsize="marquee"
singleLine="true"
layout_width="match_parent"
layout_width="wrap_content"
```

I went through dozens of questions here at stackoverflow, but it just doesn't work.

**My layout file is quite simple:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_nearest_charger"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="55dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemChargerDistance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/colorCoarseDistance"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="1.2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemChargerUnits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="miles" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemChargerOperator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dot_cpo_cps_copy_5" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemChargerTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Kinross Park and Ride"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemChargerAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Junction Road" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

All I need is to show three dots when TextView `itemChargerTitle` overflows. So far none of the solutions I found worked even in Android Studio preview.

Comment: just specify an height that is different from wrap_content. otherwise, the widget will always adapt and never ellipsize the text inside it

Comment: Added `android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"` and it works for me.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/16580374/9060917

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_nearest_charger"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="55dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemChargerDistance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="1.2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemChargerUnits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="miles" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemChargerOperator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemChargerTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Kinross Parkcvcxvxcgjghjhjhjvxcvcvcvcvcv and Ride"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemChargerAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Junction Road" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I've updated width as 0dp. When you are using `android:layout_weight` make sure you are using `android:layout_width="0dp"` and total of all child `layout_weight` is 1 or 10. That means 100% width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_nearest_charger"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemChargerDistance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="1.2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorCoarseDistance"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemChargerUnits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="miles"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemChargerOperator"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dot_cpo_cps_copy_5"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemChargerTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:text="Kinross Park and Ride"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemChargerAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Junction Road"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TextView shows three dots at the end but you can't see it, because your layout is beyond the edges of the screen. Change it's parent layout android:layout_weight to 8 to match the container android:weightSum=10 and you will see your dots.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_nearest_charger"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="10">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="55dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemChargerDistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/colorCoarseDistance"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="1.2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemChargerUnits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="miles" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/itemChargerOperator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/dot_cpo_cps_copy_5" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemChargerTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Kinross Park and Ride"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemChargerAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Junction Road" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

TextView has the property of ellipsize
you can use like this

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/topicName"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:text="Very long long long long text"
  android:textColor="@color/black"
  android:textSize="16sp" />
```

it will show this text like this
Very long long long long...