# How to show three dots at the end of text view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a text view under card view I want to how three dots at the end of text view when text is long enough.

I have tried adding below lines in my text view but could not help me.

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

This is my layout below:

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:contentPadding="3dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/homeBookImage"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="232dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="232dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeBookName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/homeBookImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Someone please let me know how can I achieve desired layout. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: try settling layout_width to match_parent and run it on a device

Comment: I have image view on left so when I make it match_parent it overlaps an image view.

Comment: please share the design in the question

Comment: I have added screenshot of my layout please take a look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, How to limit width of TextView (and add three dots at the end of text)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748796/android-how-to-limit-width-of-textview-and-add-three-dots-at-the-end-of-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `ConstraintLayout` inside `CardView` and I can see that you've constrained the `TextView` properly but its width is `wrap_content` which what causing the issue. set it to `0dp` and your `android:ellipsize` and `android:singleLine` attributes will work.

Try this:

```xml
<TextView
    ...
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
android:singleLine="true" or
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Right along with this, you need to specify the width to match parent(alongside the weight as per your design).
    If the text content exceeds the length the *...* will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for your wanted length and do it from your code like this:

```
 if (yourText.length() > 30){ 
      textView = textView .substring(0, 30); //textView length is reduced to add ...
      something.setText(textView + "...");   //adding the ... at the end
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a fixed-width or match_parent

```
<TextView
       android:layout_width="200dp" // match_parent
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:text="Your text"/>
```