# Ellipsize not behaving like it's supposed to android studio xml

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, textview, ellipsize

I have a text,and i want the end to be dotted when it doesn't fit in the text view anymore,like this "The text is leaving the scre..."

This is my xml,and it doesn't work

```
[![<TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_overview_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/movie_overview_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/movie_overview_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/movie_overview_image" />
```

The text is simply getting out of the text view(The big text,the movie description,because at the cast te ellipsize is working)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can use  `android:maxLines="1"` with  `android:ellipsize="end"` in order for it to work.

Comment: wouldn't that put my text on one line?I want it on multiple lines like it already is,and the last line to be dotted at the end when the text reaches the textview's end

Comment: you should check this out bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748796/android-how-to-limit-width-of-textview-and-add-three-dots-at-the-end-of-text]