# TextView: Limit text to specific length with 3 dots

Tags: android, textview

I have TextView which should accept max 6 characters. If value has more than 6, I want to show 3 dots at the end. Used these attributes to achieve that but it just simply cut text at the end without 3 dots.

```
 android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:maxLength="6"
 android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android, How to limit width of TextView (and add three dots at the end of text)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748796/android-how-to-limit-width-of-textview-and-add-three-dots-at-the-end-of-text)

Comment: If it's a spannabe text user CharSequence . it is a bug in ellipsize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleanest and quickest way would be to do so programatically as otherwise you'd need to do hard calculations of the text size + font alongside the TextView's width

This is the cheapest

```kotlin
textView.text = if(text.length > 6) text.take(6).append("…") else text
```