# [Android]Meaning of value "marquee" of "ellipsize" attribute in TextView

Tags: android, attributes, textview

When I study about TextView in Android, I came across the attribute "ellipsize". I wonder how  "marquee" works in "ellipsize? I tried using "start", "end" and "middle" but the "marquee" value work the same  as "none" value work.
Could you please describe to me the way "marquee" works or some documents/links where I can find the right answers to my question or guidelines. Thanks in Advance, looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer this hope it may help

[What does ellipsize mean in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313996/what-does-ellipsize-mean-in-android)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this link only dial with "start", "middle" and "end" value.

Comment: u welcome, try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739721/android-ellipsise-meaning-of-the-options