# how to set ellipsize to two lines or multilines of textview in java android

Tags: java, android-layout, textview, android

I need to set `ellipsize=end` to TextView which is allowed to expand on two lines.
I've tried this code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carouselTitle"
    android:layout_width="228dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4.5dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

Please reply with an example.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview

Answer (score 4):

```
<TextView 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:ellipsize="marquee" 
 android:singleLine="false" 
 android:maxLines="2"   
 android:text="here is my text" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This one will be work:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carouselTitle"
    android:layout_width="228dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4.5dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

The only thing you missed is `android:singleLine="false"`.

And I recommend to put `android:gravity="center_vertical"` for better UI. If the text just on one line, it will be center vertically.