# Position a view after the last word of a multiline TextView

Tags: android, textview

I would like to locate a view just after the last word of a (potentially) multi-line TextView.

For example, the TextView might be two lines, with the second line being about half as long as the TextView's width. How do I locate a View just after the last word?

Comment: what exactly in this new view...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [StaticLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html) to measure the width of your text lines and place your other view at the absolute position of the the second line length.

Alternatively you could use HTML in your TextView to place some elements inside your view.

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

Supported html tags: http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into it and it definitely is the way to go.

Comment: Please sir, is this still relevant in 2022 sir or is there a clean/better way to achieve it?