# TextView multiline

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView that is populated with a text that is taken from a database, so its lenth is undefined.

I have configured the TextView using the maxline attribute, and I have set its value to 3, because I don't want more than 3 lines of text, and also I use the ellipsize attribute.

But It doesn't work properly. Although the text is larger than 3 lines, it only prints two lines.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/etLugar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvLugar"        
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvLugar"
    android:text="A very large text than must be shown in the textview, but no more of three lines are going to be shown"
    android:textColor="@color/foreground1"        
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:ellipsize="end"        
    android:textSize="12dp" 
    />
```

I don't understand why maxlines attribute is is not working properly. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Make use for String length and Sub String to limit :)

Comment: Are there `\n` in the `android:text` property? Only then it's a new line it think.

Answer (score 3):

i guess it is due to `android:singleLine="false"` which is default value try and change it to `TRUE`
tell if it works.

Comment: singleLine is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

There is same question [Android ellipsize multiline textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview). This is known bug, quite old and not fixed yet.

Someone posted workaround [Android Textview Multiline Ellipse/](http://code.google.com/p/android-textview-multiline-ellipse/) maybe it will help you (or someone else).

Comment: Hello, I've tried the solution I've read in the question you told me, but it doesn't work. Again, two lines but now it is not ellipsed...

Answer (score 0):

Because of you have less content that has two line only, it was work perfectly which you wrote code(xml) enter more content in string then try it.

image [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue with 2 TextView, one is supposed to have maxLines="2" and the other maxLines="4".

The first was always on a single line, regardless of the ellipsize setting I add.
The second didn't matter and text was using as many lines it needed!

It seems to depends on 2 factors:

1. The other elements of your layout
2. The textAppearance if set may break/override this setting or a singleLine option

To solve this I added code to do that directly on the text views:

```
tv1.setMaxLines(2);
tv2.setMaxLines(4);
```

And that did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the `ellipsize` attribute, just `android:maxlines="3"` should work.

Comment: Ok, it works, three line are shown, but now the ellipse is not shown

Comment: Are you using default font or custom.  I ran into this and the ellipse was not defined in the font so it ended up drawing a space.

Comment: For whatever I did, it was the default font. Never tried  with other fonts, but that should not matter, if I'm  not wrong.