# "Ellipsize" only shows one dot

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

On my Samsung Galaxy Nexus, behavior is OK, it shows three dots, but in Samsung S2, it shows only one dot. There is only one layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewOfferTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewRedemptionDate"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/pontai_dark_gray"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ndp_font_size" />
```

This is the example:

http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/5118/96452147.png

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Does this happen for all of your text views on the GS2?  I know Samsung does some weird things with their UI, especially on their older devices, so it might be a product of that.

Comment: I've seen some Sony Ericsson devices showing squares instead of ... :S

Comment: @Warpzit Yeah, a lot of manufacturers like to put their own skins on top of things and it leads to lots of little disparities in functionality.  Forget little things though, the old Motoblur skin from Motorola was just downright unusable at times.

Comment: Hey guys. I am not sure to be honest if other screens using ellipsize in GS2 are having the same behaviour. I will take a look. This is quite annoying! :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee on how text will be ellipsized (a single dot is a little misleading if you ask me, but it can be interpreted as an abreviation). If you want to ensure the "three-dots" behavior, you are free to subclass `TextView`and add your custom behavior. An example can be seen [on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6763689/1379847) (just do not bother with the "multiple line" part of the code).
Long story short, a single dot for ellipsis should not be an issue.

Comment: Why the downvote? A single dot is the "Samsung Galaxy SII way" of ellipsizing, what's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 3):

remove

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

and try

```
android:lines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

It works for me.

Comment: I heared that some device used lines & ellipsize would lead to crash, and this is still not fixed