# Adding an custom EllipsizingTextView to a layout

Tags: java, android

I came across the problem that android only supports ellipsizing a TextView with 2 lines. I found the solution here [android ellipsize multiline textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview)

However I'm now my textviews are getting displayed strangely, so instead of:

```
This is a test...
```

My TextView dispalys

```
This
is
a
```

Also the EllipsizingTextView seems to effect another TextView in the same layout which hasn't been declared to be a EllipsizingTextView but a regular TextView. Anyway here's the offending code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View itemView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = itemView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        EllipsizingTextView desc = new EllipsizingTextView(parent.getContext());
        desc.setMaxLines(3);
        layout.addView(desc);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.label = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);
        vh.img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
        vh.desc = (EllipsizingTextView) desc;
        vh.dateAdded = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDateAdded);
        v.setTag(vh);
    }
```

And the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="0px"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="16sp" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:textColor="#000" android:singleLine="true"
    />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDateAdded"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="13sp"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it by removing the statements where I was adding the ElipsizingTextView programmatically and added the view via the XML with the element name of`<com.example.EllipsizingTextView`

Anyone know what I was doing wrong when adding the view programmatically?