# Android: Line-limited textview with "..." to show that there is more content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, textview

I am displaying a long (random) text in a TextView. I want to show 3 lines in this TextView and show dots (...) if there is more content. I know I can limit the lines of a TextView with minLines and maxLines, but I don't know where to add the dots in the string.

E.g. the TextView could/should look like

```
"This i random text
 this is a short one
 and more is here..."

"This one has a very
 loooooooooooooooong
 string so where ..."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know where to add the dots, the TextView can do it for you. Checkout [`android:ellipsize=end`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize). Note that the ellipsize's algorithm doesn't work reliably in older android versions. There might be discrepancies between the exact behavior between 2.3, 3 and 4+. For example I know that it will not show more than two lines in 2.3

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple algorithm that checks which word is displayed at X characters and after or before this word, you can add the dots.

Comment: but i don't know which word is displayed at the last position of an TextView. A TextView shows e.g different amount of words according to the size of the mobile phone.. (small device shows e.g. 9 words, large device shows 14 words)