# ellipsize is not working in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want to `android:ellipsize` the text in `AutoCompleteTextView`. Tried the following code, but it not working.

Can someone help me?

Here is the code:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
          android:id="@+id/address_text"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:completionThreshold="3"
          android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
          android:imeActionLabel="Search"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:ellipsize="end" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think **AutocompleteTextView** is not feasible for **ellipSize** but we can set **ellipsize** customize,Below is the code,

```
        String fullText = "Give your text here";
        int width = autocompleteTextview.getMeasuredWidth() - (autocompleteTextview.getPaddingLeft()+autocompleteTextview.getPaddingRight());

        String truncatedText = TextUtils.ellipsize(mFullText, autocompleteTextview.getPaint(), width, TextUtils.TruncateAt.END).toString();
        if(truncatedText!=null&& truncatedText.length()>0){
            autocompleteTextview.setText(truncatedText);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:completionThreshold="1"`

Answer (score -1):

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/product"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:tag="product"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

In the adapter or any class , where ever you using the autotextview set Threshold to 1

Comment: ,where are you setting ellipsize property?

Comment: see this it might help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview)

Comment: it's not working for me. My app force closes, when I use `android:ellipsize="marquee"` on my autocompletetextview. Please help me out..

Answer (score -1):

```
private String mclientName;
```

> Put the code in oncreate()

```
mClientName=new ArrayList<String>(); 
mClientName.add("abc");
mClientName.add("abc");
mClientName.add("abc");
mClientName.add("abc");
mClientName.add("abc");


((AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.etschoolname)).setText(mcollegeName
                                    .equalsIgnoreCase("") ? "" : mcollegeName);
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserEditEducationActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,mClientName);
                            ((AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.etschoolname)).setThreshold(1);
                            ((AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.etschoolname)).setAdapter(adapter);
                            ((AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.etschoolname)).setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                        View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),(CharSequence)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            });
```

**

> and xml

**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView 
                    android:id="@+id/etschoolname"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_margin="10dip"

                    android:hint=""
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:maxLength="120"
                    android:paddingBottom="-10dip" />
```