# Can't get text to wrap and use ellipsis in Android 2.3

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview that should show a maximum of 5 lines and wrap the text. It should also show an ellipsis if the text is too long. The following works using Android 4.1 but not on 2.3. If I set scrollHorizontally to false, I only get 2 lines. Is there anything I can do to get the same result under 4.1?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ivIcon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivIcon"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known bug. Here's one solution I came across:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6763689/753632

But that's over 2 years old. Not sure if someone came up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must try android:Lines in place of android.maxLines