# TextView's ellipsize not working on maxLines = 1

Tags: android, textview

I really cannot figure out why, but I am only able to get ellipsize working on `maxLines=2` and more. I am displaying a few words of description and then a long string with no spaces.

This is how the TextView looks like:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#757575"
                android:text="@string/gcm_not_registered"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:id="@+id/login_gcmRegistrationTextView"/>
```

I then programatically set a text to it, but depending on the maxLines limitation, I get two different results:

[image: maxLines=1] [image: maxlines=2]

The only thing that changed was the `maxLines`, why isn't the line filled in the first picture as well?

Comment: I needed this too in my app and this answer did the job http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: do you have  \n in your string somewhere??

Comment: I don't. It is a GCM ID, so it's just plain text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to fix it:

1. Try to change `android:ellipsize="end"` attribute to `android:ellipsize="marquee"`.
2. Try to remove `android:maxLines="1" android:ellipsize="end"` attributes and add `android:singleLine="true"` attribute.

Comment: The 2) worked. But I wonder why, when I didn't say I wanted the text to be ellipsized, it shouldn't be. I also read that it is deprecated, but looking all over the documentation I can't find a word of it. So thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This code works for me:

In the xml add:

- Attribute `ellipsize`: `marquee`
- Attribute `lines`: `1`

In java:

```
<yourTextView>.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
<yourTextView>.setSelected(true);
```

If there is another item that request the "focus" you lose the marquee effect. The `textView` need the state selected to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is with the spannable text, if you set spannable text this wouldn't work. Other than this below code works for me

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_second"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textColor="#b3277b"
    android:background="#f7ecff"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv"
    android:text="This is first line\nThis is second line\nThis is third line"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    />
```