# Ellipsize not working (for single line)

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to get ellipsize to work for a single line of text inside a TextView. I've already tried all the workarounds (e.g. scrollHorizontally, singleLine, lines, etc.) below previous questions, but nothing seems to happen. This is my code (tested on an HTC One M8 (5.0.1)):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:background="@drawable/file_tile_background" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/file_tile_imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_drive_file_black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/file_tile_imageview_description" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/file_tile_textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/file_tile_imageview"
    android:text="@string/file_tile_textview_fileName"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: Maybe it doesn't like that I include this layout in activity_main.xml and doesn't use it directly?

Comment: Is the text being cut off at some point?

Comment: Yes, it's simply cut off. Doesn't wrap in the next line because of maxLines="1", but also doesn't ellipsize like it should....

Comment: It would only be a problem if it were wrap_content, since wrap_content will allow the TextView to expand as long as it needs to (including running off the screen)

Comment: How are you including it? I assume you mean using `<include>` but do you have any attributes set in the `<include>` tag?

Comment: No, only <include layout="@layout/file_tile" />

Comment: Try android:ellipsize="end" , lines="1" and layout_width="wrap_content"

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution is to use `android:singleLine="true"`.

You can find the related solution on the following link.

> [TextView's ellipsize not working on maxLines = 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351698/textviews-ellipsize-not-working-on-maxlines-1?rq=1)