# Detect where Android's TextView would insert a line break

Tags: android, textview, multiline

I have a rectangular tile, and I want to fit an image and some text into it. The image must not overlap the text, and the sizes of the image and the text can vary.

The process **must** be hand-coded, since we have to fine-tune it according to our client's needs.

I tried the approach of first measuring the rendered text bounds using `getTextBounds()` or `measureText()` and then adapting the font size and the image size so they don't overlap.

This works fine if the text is only on one line.

But if `TextView` wraps the text onto multiple line, I cannot predict the text bounds, since I don't know where `TextView` would insert the automatic line breaks.

**How can I find out the positions in the text where `TextView` inserts an automatic line break?**

**Example:** Given the text

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`

which would be rendered as

```
| Lorem ipsum    |
| dolor sit amet |
```

I need a function that converts

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`

to

`Lorem ipsum \ndolor sit amet`

Comment: see StaticLayout class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TextView (Layout object) has some useful functions for what you are trying to accomplish:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html

take a look at:

`getLineCount()`

`getLineEnd(int line)`

You can get the substring for the TextView string based on where the character is located at each lineEnd.

You will need to use `getViewTreeObserver()` to wait until the TextView is drawn before you can call these and get useful information from them.

Alternatively, you can build a custom TextView that might provide the data through built-in methods or by adding a listener to it. An example of a custom TextView that modifies text size is here:

[android ellipsize multiline textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview)

I've used that and did similar modifications (like what you are trying to do).

Comment: If the _TextView_ is already drawn, you must call it from a different thread or else the line count won't be correct.
`textview.post(new Runnable{
    int lineCount = textview.getLineCount();
});`

Answer (score 4):

You'd probably want to wrap this logic into a custom view (overriding `onSizeChanged()`) but you can use the `Layout` class to check where each line ends:

```
textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // Remove immediately so it only fires once
        textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        // View should be laid out, including text placement
        final Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
        float maxLineWidth = 0;

        // Loop over all the lines and do whatever you need with
        // the width of the line
        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++) {
            maxLineWidth = Math.max(maxLineWidth, layout.getLineWidth(i));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an TextWatcher and extract the single lines

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
 String str =  editable.toString();
 Layout layout = textView.getLayout();

 ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
 for (int i = 0; i < textView.getLineCount(); i++) 
 {
    int lineStart = layout.getLineStart(i);
    int lineEnd = layout.getLineEnd(i);

    String lineString = str.substring(lineStart, lineEnd);
     lines.add(lineString);
   }
   // now you have the single lines
}
```