# Android TextView: how to set line breaks in 2 TextViews to be the same

Tags: android

My problem seems apparently simple, but I have not been able to find a solution.

I have 2 TextViews, they have the SAME TEXT but have

- different size of TextView;
- different size of the font of the text inside the TextView.

I HAVE NO CONTROL OVER THE TEXT (it comes from remote).

I wish to have the 2 TextViews to have the line break exactly at the same point

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a text to one of the TextViews and then use the text inside as a source for the second text view using:

[Detect where Android's TextView would insert a line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365379/detect-where-androids-textview-would-insert-a-line-break)

The second text view should have a little more "width capacity" to be able to place everything what is in the first view without making its "own" line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the max length of characters in one line of both the textViews. This can be done by using a property   for the TextViews in the layout where they are defined:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="12" />
```

Comment: Thanks kamal2305 but that will not work:-((  : since the TextViews have different dimensions and different characters size it's impossible to determine the ideal lenght. Additionally `maxLength` it's a dimension (in px or dp) not the number of characters

Comment: Please follow the link:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLength