# Android: How to make multiline TextView?

Tags: android, listview, textview

Good day!

I have a ListView with news list, but if the title is very long- he lost on the edge of the screen.

How do I text-wrap to the next line?
I read many posts about this, but can not find solution that works to me.

Here the code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    >
</ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.app.SportNewsReaderApp.NewsActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"

    android:textSize="16.5dip"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:minLines = "1"
    android:maxLines = "100"
    android:singleLine = "false"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" 
    android:lines="2"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [android ellipsize multiline textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I text-wrap to the next line?

by removing `minLines` attribute