# Ellipsize = "end" not using

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have body code:

```
<TextView
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
    android:textAppearance="@style/FontPath.Light"
    android:id="@+id/tv_content_notification"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I using `android:ellipsize="end"` but when running it displays the following:

[image]

Comment: add android:singleLine="true"

Comment: what's the exact problem that you are facing?

Comment: @Anatha Raju . Later "..." have a text

Comment: @sasikumar .I want Textview has maxLines ="3" but android:singleLine="true" work for maxLines="1"

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160619/android-ellipsize-multiline-textview

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will work

```
android:maxLines="3"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="false"
```

OR

try to use `ViewTreeObserver` and you need to calculate lines fit into textview with its height and then set maxlength

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int maxLines = (int) textView.getHeight()
                / textView.getLineHeight();
        textView.setMaxLines(maxLines);
        textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(
                this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I try this your xml code the results did not change

Comment: I try your editted your answer but the result did not change.